# Using glade with python

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, glade

The only tutorials I can seem to find are about glade's interface itself. I'm trying to figure out how to import the .glade file into python to add functionality. The tutorials that did manage to show source file provided no info on how they got the .glade file into the IDE. I'm currently using Pycharm 5 with python 3.4. I've tried adding the .glade file to my project file as a .py file but the source code looks very strange, almost like html. I am using glade 3.18. Help please?

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried adding the .glade file to my project file as a .py file but the source code looks very strange, almost like html.

Yes it is just XML that describes the UI.

Here is a decent guide on how to load it from Python and use it - https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/builder.html

Comment: Apparently I don't have everything I need because I can't import Gtk

Comment: Just to clarify you are doing `from gi.repository import Gtk`? What distro and I can point out some package names maybe.

Comment: I'm still getting an unresolved reference for Gtk. I'm using Kali Sana, it's a debian distro

Comment: I already have everyone of them in their latest versions. Still no luck :/

Comment: You have this too: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python-gobject ? (An exact error would help)

Comment: I have all of the packages above in their latest versions. I am still getting an unresolved reference for Gtk. The only module I can find that includes gtk is called pygtkcompat